# Adding navigation bar to external sites

Tags: javascript, html

For links to external content on my website I would like the user to see the external content with my navigation bar remaining at the top of the page.
I want it so when the user visits the external content even if they scroll down my navigation bar will remain fixed to the top of the page. I currently have this working for internal content but can't think of a good way of implementing this for external content such as webpages or images.

How could I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: I think your only option here is to use an iframe.

Comment: But how would I make the iframe fill the whole content height?

Comment: Same as any other element,  make html/body/iframe 100% height - or if you run into problems with that use javascript.  You'll be keeping the visitors on your site so you'll have control of the top level window - and just show the external content in the iframe.  You'll probably run into issues if they use the external content to navigate somewhere else.  Not convinced there is a clean way of doing this as it's quite an intrusive hack.

Comment: Cheers, I wanted to avoid Iframes really but if it's the only way I don't have much of a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have this be valid you need to use a frame.

Loading the content in an ajax request and appending it to your page will invalidate your page.

If you do go the route of making an ajax call you'll have to parse the result to get only the bits you want to show. This will be tricky, especially if the site has stylesheet,s JS files, etc.

Also, Ajax calls do not work across domains. There are things you can do and frameworks you can use to make these kinds of cross domain calls, but personally I think it's overkill given your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery `.load()` function found [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Simply specify a div in which to load the content and the url. Example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea if you can be sure the external content isn't going to do anything nasty as you'll be loading it onto a page that is running under your domain... that's nasty as in interfering with styling/structure of the HTML and nasty as in executing arbitrary javascript.

Comment: As far as I know, the load() method will not allow you to make cross-domain requests.

Comment: But if it's loading external webpages it will include <html> and <body> tags. Also how will it handle the CSS? Will it affect my styles if I'm loading everything into a <div> on my page?

Comment: Very true. I assumed the external content was his but this may not be the case, and as you said it can interfere with styling. I do not think you can do cross domain requests without a hack such as https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax .. although I have not tried this. My mistake, given the needs an iframe would probably be the most simple solution.